# div top position on hover remembered after magnific popup initialisation

Tags: javascript, html, css, absolute, magnific-popup

I've been working with magnific popup which is a fantastic little script. I've had one issue lately though.

I've made an example on codepen to isolate the problem - http://codepen.io/patrickwc/pen/xiajJ

Basically, when you hover over the `figure` element, `figcaption` moves up via changing the `top` value. Then I've made a link absolutely positioned over the entire of that `figcaption` element, so that when you click or tap again the link magnific popup window is activated. This part works fine, but for some reason in some browsers, when you exit the magnific popup window (close or clicking outside makes no difference) the `figcaption` element gets "stuck". I'd like it to return to where it was before the hover event, as it does in most browsers. But for some reason in IE11 and Chrome Canary (latest stable Chrome is fine) seem to remember that the element was hovered, and the figcaption box gets stuck there, unless you hover again.

Usual behaviour you can see in most browsers.

IE11 and Chrome Canary (Version 39.0.2152.0 canary) after closing popout window:
[image]

Interestingly this does not happen on browserstack. I have Windows 8.1 and Chrome Canary 37, as well as IE11 and the behaviour is fine on browserstack, but not on my or others PCs.

I realise I should probably use transform to get hardware accelerated transforms, but I need IE8 support. I'm going to see if transforms make any difference now, but I'm guessing they won't. Maybe I'll have to use js instead of the hover event to move the `figcaption` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got some help from the developer of magnific popup and a friend of mine who's a javascript wizz. The `.open-popup-link` a tag was being focussed, once the popup had closed. I found out about jquery's `blur` [event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and the following code fixed the issue, which only happened in IE11 and Chrome Canary (v38 and 39).

```
jQuery('.open-popup-link').on('focus',function(){
    jQuery(this).blur();
})
```